# C++ program to accept int and print *

Tags: c++

I am self studying C++ and I was thinking of a simple program to get comfortable with the syntax.

```
int main(){
int num;
cout << "Enter a positive number:";
cin >> num;
printStar(num);
}

void printStar(int num){
.............................
}
```

Such that the function printStar accepts an integer and prints `*` for instance accepts 3 and prints `***` or accepts 6 and prints `******` or accepts 2 and prints `**`. I was thinking of using a for or while loop and getting it done any better ideas suggestions?

Comment: 1. try your solution. Post the code and what you got and then we can tell you if there's a better way of doing it

Comment: If you need something to iterate over, loop is definitely necessary. Either of the looping statements is fine. Btw, added an extra `*` when 2 is accepted.

Comment: @Mahesh Putting a lot of effort into editing I see. ;-)

Comment: @Mahesh You're forgetting about recursion :P

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes - I definitely thought of someone is going to point it out :(

Comment: Not a loop recursion. That will make it interesting. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is for your own learning, i am not giving a solution, a hint is using For or While loop. If it works, its good, otherwise post your code and problem.

[A link to get you started](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/)

Comment: Thank you all, but this comment was most helpful in my context! Cheers

Answer (score 3):

You can use `std::string`:

```
using namespace std;
cout << string(num, '*') << endl;
```

or the STL's `fill_n`:

```
using namespace std;
fill_n(ostream_iterator<char>(cout, ""), num, '*');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `cout.fill`:

```
cout.fill('*');
cout.width(num);
cout << ' ' << endl;
```

Note that this messes with a lot of stuff, so you should capture and reset the fill and width:

```
char oldfill = cout.fill('*');
streamsize w = cout.width();
cout.fill('*');
cout.width(num);
cout << ' ' << endl;
cout.width(w);
cout.fill(oldfill);
```